# webpack publicPath - Use different urls to reuse bundles

Tags: webpack, lazy-loading, code-splitting, splitchunksplugin, code-splitting-async

Given the following scenario.

A webpack build producing 3 bundles, and a CI publishing them to a CDN like this (every build id produces a new folder):

```
www.cdn.com/1/application.js
www.cdn.com/1/chunk-a.js
www.cdn.com/1/chunk-b.js
```

now, consider that the next build produces:

```
www.cdn.com/2/application.js
www.cdn.com/2/chunk-a.js
www.cdn.com/2/chunk-b.js
```

It might happen that some of these files are identical, let's say that nothing changes but `application.js`. We have a script that produces a [manifest](https://github.com/bundle-stats/bundle-stats), it simply compares these two builds and produces:

```
{
  files: [
    'www.cdn.com/1/chunk-a.js', 
    'www.cdn.com/1/chunk-b.js', 
    'www.cdn.com/2/application.js'
  ]
}
```

---

#### we want to hook into the webpack chunk loader strategy and load the chunks from the build `1`, since there is no reason to invalidate any client cache.

To be more specific, we want to patch the release, so that we can reuse static assets if possible.

---

we want a hook that retrieves the request and returns a url that webpack will then use to load the asset, something like:

```
interface Hook {
  (chunk: string): string
}

hook('chunk-a') => 'www.cdn.com/1/chunk-a.js'
hook('chunk-b') => 'www.cdn.com/1/chunk-b.js'
hook('application.js') => 'www.cdn.com/2/application.js'
```

---

1. [webpack feature request to use `__webpack_public_path__`](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/9518)

Answer (score 1):

As per Aug 2019, this is **currently not possible with webpack@4**. A pull request has been merged into `webpack@next` and will deliver a feature exposing how url is generated in webpack@5.

```
__webpack_get_script_filename__ = (asset: string) => string
```

https://github.com/webpack/webpack/pull/8462